# Some basic questions about starting iOS development

Tags: swift2, app-store

I am new to iOS development and hoping to get some advice. Looking to publish my first app, it is going to be a swift 2.0 spritekit based 2d game. so here are my questions

1. I have a Macbook, an iPad and iPad mini but no iphone. Should i get the latest iphone 6 or iphone 5 is enough for my testing?
2. I like to make two versions of same app, one for iPhones and other for iPads. Can that is submitted to the app store? (i am trying to avoid handling different screens in one app)
3. I tested cocos2d, but the project i build had a lot of warnings even for a default hello world project. Will this cause a problem getting the game approved later?

that's all

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a generic question but I'll try

1) probably advisable to have at least an iPhone 6, if you want to use 3D Touch than you need a 6S.

2) you can submit 2 apps to the appStore but you probably just want to make a universal app that runs both on iPads and iPhones, no need for separate apps. Would also cause you more work and bug fixing. You cannot really avoid dealing with different screens, but it's very easy to make your game look good on all screen sizes.

3) not sure because I never used cocoas.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to get an iPhone 6 for testing. It's a lot better if you will test it on a real device, but you can use the xcode simulator for testing as well (and you have there a lot of devices)

Make an universal app, it's for iPhone and Ipad

You can upload a project with warnings to the app store, and it can be approved.